# Dinamizar title com AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Quero dinamizar meu `title` de página com AngularJS. Atualmente é estatico:

```
<title>Workspace</title>
```

Gostaria de saber como posso trocar esse nome, baseado no que está gravado no *database*. Atualmente em um local onde o cliente irá fazer a modificação (`input`) está assim:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="workspace.titlePage" id="inputPageTitle" placeholder="Define here the title of the page" class="ng-valid ng-dirty">
```

Porém, isso acontece em outra página (`workspace-admin.html`), lá está conseguindo adicionar na base de dados e enxergar as informações em `{{workspace.titlePage}}`. Gostaria de obter a mesma informação, porém em outra página (`index.html`).

Mas, quando faço `{{workspace.titlePage}}`, ele me retorna `undefined`, já que até o momento não foi carregado a diretiva responsável por esse valor.

Como posso pegar esse valor?

Comment: Oi, Edmo :) Pras suas futuras perguntas (ou respostas), temos um guia orientativo legal: [Como devemos formatar perguntas e respostas?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1084/201). Quando alguém edita um post (P ou R), podemos ver o [histórico de edição](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/40378/revisions) e a partir daí aprender como funciona a formatação aqui no Stack. Saudações,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pode criar um evento no `$rootScope` na pagina `workspace-admin.html` e subscrever esse evento na pagina `index.html`:

Ou seja, no *controller* de `workspace-admin.html`:

```
// emissao do evento
$rootscope.$emit("titlechanged@workspaceadmin", titulo);
```

E depois no *controller* de `index.html`:

```
this.tituloPagina = "PlaceHolder";

// escuta do evento
var eventHolder = $rootScope.$on("titlechanged@workspaceadmin", function(titulo){
    this.tituloPagina = titulo.
});
```

Por fim em `index.html`:

```
<title>{{tituloPagina}}</title>
```

Comment: Obrigado @Omni achei algo nesse sentido que você me disse:http://nomadev.com.br/como-comunicar-diferentes-controllers-no-angularjs/ e deu super certo